# Splitting FullName in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to split Fullname with this sql code that I got from someone here in Stack Overflow however it won't work because the format of the Fullname is like this "LastName, FirstName Middle Initial" and there are names that don't have middle initials.

```
select left(m.fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', m.fullname)) as [Last Name]
      ,substring(m.fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', m.fullname)+1
      ,len(m.fullname)-(CHARINDEX(' ', m.fullname)-1)) as [First Name]
From Temp
```

Can someone please let me know how to query this. The example format will be like this:

```
FullName: Smith, John D
```

Desired Output:

```
LastName    FirstName
Smith        John
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please tag the DBMS name.

Comment: Are names separated by commas as in your example or spaces?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using MicrosoftSQLServer2014

Comment: Name are separated by commas

Answer (score 1):

Split your string using using the comma. The result should be an array. Index zero will be the last name, and index one will be the first name.

Comment: The question is tagged with `[tsql]` while your answer points to a programming language like C#...

Comment: That's just the logic. Many SQL databases works this way.

Comment: Nope, databases work set-based. Your *create an array and pick some elements per index* is procedural thinking. Well, such an issue is not *database thinking* at all, as such a value should never occur in any database (1.NF!). But even the new `STRING_SPLIT()` function (SS2017+) does not carry the elements index...  Furthermore the parts seem to need another split at blanks...

Answer (score 1):

Parsing a "full name" into first, middle, and last name is not straightforward in a database. Don't try it unless this is just a homework that considers simplified non-real life cases.

Parsing a full name requires non trivial logic to recognize all kinds of cases. There are several reasons for it:

- Most languages have multi word first and last names. They are not hyphenated as in the US but they include bona fide multiple word each. Even some US (very few) names have multiple words.
- Some people have middle name or none at all.
- Some people include suffixes as part of their name:

  - "Jr", "Sr" are patronimic ones.
  - "PhD", "Esquire" are title ones.
  - There are more complicated cases that convey different kind of information.
- In some languages first and last names are inverted. Korean for example.
- You need to consider that names can have special characters: "O'Hara" for example. Pretty much anything can be valid, depending on the language.
- You need to consider using unicode, to recognize alphabetic symbols correctly. French anyone? Russian? Mandarin?
- Finally, you need to consider a myriad of special cases. That is, you need a knowledge base to resolve all kinds of situations, that won't be covered by the "normal" rules you'll use.

Of course, all of the above can be done using SQL. However, SQL is not the right option IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parsename()` function :

```
select fullname, parsename(replace(fullname, ' ', '.'), 3) as lastname,
                 parsename(replace(fullname, ' ', '.'), 2) as firstname
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to The Impaler's answer here's an answer how you might split your FullName. This will not solve the very well explained issues with naming rules, but - at least - you get hands on each part in a strucutured format:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, FullName NVARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES(N'Smith, John D')
                         ,(N'Parker, Dr. James');

SELECT CAST(N'<x><y>' 
              + REPLACE(
                  REPLACE(
                            (SELECT FullName AS [*] FOR XML PATH(''))
                           ,N','
                           ,N'</y></x><x><y>'
                         )
                         ,N' '
                         ,N'</y><y>') 
              + N'</y></x>' AS XML)
              .query(
                      N'
                        for $x in /x
                        return 
                        <x>
                        {
                            for $y in $x/y[text()]
                            return $y
                        }
                        </x>
                        '
                   )
FROM @mockup;
```

The result for the first name

```
<x>
  <y>Smith</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>John</y>
  <y>D</y>
</x>
```

And for the second

```
<x>
  <y>Parker</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>Dr.</y>
  <y>James</y>
</x>
```

You see, that the comma separated parts are found within `<x>` while the blank separated parts are found as nested `<y>`.